# Is it possible to generate step by step report in Jenkins for selenium execution

Tags: selenium, jenkins, report, jenkins-plugins

I want to know is there any way of generating a step by step execution report in Jenkins. Suppose if I'm executing my Selenium tests and it gets failed at a particular step, then the report should display at which step it got failed. Is there any way in Jenkins to do this?

Thanks

Comment: You can look for maven surefire report plugin to achieve your goal

Answer (score 0):

you can use build automation script reporting features, example... run Selinium tests in Jenkins  using Ant or Maven or Gradle and generate detailed reports.

Comment: But adding those won't give me detailed step by step report. Whether a particular step passed or not?